# Virtualbox installation in SLES11 SP2

Tags: linux, virtualbox, rpm

Trying to install `virtualbox` in `SLES11 SP2`

Downlaod the source rpm from `https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads`

**Installed it like**

```
rpm -ivh VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.20_96996_sles11.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

**Getting this error**

`Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules`                                    **done**

`Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules`                       **done**

`Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS`

> Error! Your kernel source for kernel 3.0.13-0.27-default cannot be found at
>   /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-default/build or /lib/modules/3.0.13-0.27-default/source.
>
> ```
>                                                                  failed
> ```
>
> (Failed, trying without DKMS)
>
> Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                                 **failed**

Any idea what might possibly be the reason.

Thanks in advance.

/Suvasish

Comment: Is there something in the error message that isn't clear? The installer needs to build some kernel modules for your specific kernel, and in order to do so, needs the kernel sources.  The installer is expecting them to be in one of the given directories, hut didn't find them. You need to install you kernel sources.